# Docker Container restarts automatically

Tags: docker

I have two docker containers which are linked. The first one is a mariadb database and the other one is a MediaWiki instance. I don't need these two anymore, that's why I would like to stop and remove them.

My Problem is now, that I can't do that.
I tried a lot of things already:

Executing `docker update --restart=no "containers"`. But it keeps restarting after I stop the container with `docker container stop "container"`.

Tried to remove the images with no joy as they are in use by the containers (even if I kill the container and then quickly try to delete the image)

Restarted the entire Docker service with `systemctl restart docker`.

I even restarted my entire Server.

All of these with no positive result.
I'm kinda frustated.

I got 2 more containers running very well. (pyload and netdata). No problems at all with them.

As I'm new in the Docker world, please tell me what you need to help me :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you use `docker-compose`?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more explicit and detailed about what it is with which you need help. If you're seeing error messages (on the console and logs) dealing with these commands, please provide those as well. Please get help and fix some of the grammar issues in your question. Best of luck.

Comment: @rath: nope, I don't.

Comment: @JohnSchmitt: So please tell me, which log do you want to see. I do not get any error message at the console. If you only came here to fix my grammar, please go help anyone else. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Killing the container does not delete them. You have to remove the stopped containers before you can remove the images.

`docker ps` shows you the list of current running container. `docker ps -a` will show the list of all the containers (stopped and running).

First clean up all the containers that are not running via `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`

Then delete the images that you dont want `docker rmi $(docker images)`

Comment: uhm, I said before that the containers do not stop. Even if I say `docker container stop "container"`.
That's quite obvious that I can't delete the images when the containers are running. I can't even stop them, that's my main problem...

Comment: `docker stop "container_name"` doesnt remove it from the `docker ps` list?

Comment: it removes it, but just for about 4-5 seconds. Then it appears again in the ps list and also in the running container list.

Comment: How did you start your containers? using docker-compose or docker swarm or kubernetes? it seems some service is respawning your containers

Comment: Hi, sorry, did not see your message. As far as I remember I started the container just by running "docker run..." As so much time has passed, I do not remember at all how I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset to factory setting by clicking the bug icon of docker desktop and choose "reset to factory default". It will remove everything. It worked for me. I spent days to figure this out and finally I got it. Hopefully it helps you too!